# not able to observe the sqlite database changes

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-livedata

I am developing an app that constructs the path taken by user on the map
i am using sqlite database for that as a requirement
from the database i am returning mutablelivedata and on the map activity observing it
but the observer is not observing anything
i have tried handler too and timmer

here is the maps activity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private ActivityMapsBinding binding;

private Location lastKnownLocation;
private boolean locationPermissionGranted;
private PlacesClient placesClient;
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
private final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 121;
private final int REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION = 0;
DatabaseHandler db;


private final PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
private final PolylineOptions polylineOptionsRed = new PolylineOptions();
private final PolylineOptions polylineOptionsGreen = new PolylineOptions();
private final PolylineOptions polylineOptionsBlue = new PolylineOptions();
private final PolylineOptions polylineOptionsYellow = new PolylineOptions();


private final LocationCallback locationcallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()
        ) {

            TrackingEntity trackingEntity = new 
    TrackingEntity(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), location.getLatitude(), 
    location.getLongitude());

            db.insertTrack(trackingEntity);


            LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), 
location.getLongitude());

            float zoomLevel = 18.0f;
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, zoomLevel);
            mMap.moveCamera(update);
        }

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);


    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.google_maps_key));
    placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);


    boolean isActivityRecognitionPermissionFree = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 29;
    boolean isActivityRecognitionPermissionGranted = EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, new 
String[]{"android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"});


    db.getAllVisitors().observe(this, trackingEntity -> {

        if (trackingEntity != null) {

            if (Red) {
                addLocationToRouteRed(trackingEntity);
            } else if (Green) {
                addLocationToRouteGreen(trackingEntity);
            } else if (Blue) {
                addLocationToRouteBlue(trackingEntity);
            } else if (Yellow) {
                addLocationToRouteYellow(trackingEntity);
            } else {
                addLocationToRoute(trackingEntity);
            }
        }


    });

    if (!isActivityRecognitionPermissionFree && !isActivityRecognitionPermissionGranted) {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "For", REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION, new 
String[]{"android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"});
    } else {
        setupLocationChangeListener();


    }

}

private final void addLocationToRoute(TrackingEntity lastTrackingEntity) {
    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.clear();
        LatLng newLatLng = lastTrackingEntity.asLatLng();
        polylineOptions.getPoints().add(newLatLng);
        mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
    }

}

private final void addLocationToRouteRed(TrackingEntity lastTrackingEntity) {
    polylineOptionsRed.color(-65536);
    LatLng newLatLng = lastTrackingEntity.asLatLng();
    polylineOptionsRed.getPoints().add(newLatLng);
    mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptionsRed);
}

private final void addLocationToRouteGreen(TrackingEntity lastTrackingEntity) {
    polylineOptionsGreen.color(-16711936);
    LatLng newLatLng = lastTrackingEntity.asLatLng();
    polylineOptionsGreen.getPoints().add(newLatLng);
    mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptionsGreen);
}

private final void addLocationToRouteBlue(TrackingEntity lastTrackingEntity) {
    polylineOptionsBlue.color(-16776961);
    LatLng newLatLng = lastTrackingEntity.asLatLng();
    polylineOptionsBlue.getPoints().add(newLatLng);
    mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptionsBlue);
}

private final void addLocationToRouteYellow(TrackingEntity lastTrackingEntity) {
    polylineOptionsYellow.color(-256);
    LatLng newLatLng = lastTrackingEntity.asLatLng();
    polylineOptionsYellow.getPoints().add(newLatLng);
    mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptionsYellow);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    getLocationPermission();
    updateLocationUI();
    getDeviceLocation();

}

private final void setupLocationChangeListener() {
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, new String[] 
   {"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"})) {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setPriority(100);
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000L);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
    "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION") != 0 && 
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission((Context) this, 
    "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION") != 0) {
            return;
        }

        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationRequest,
                locationcallback,
                Looper.getMainLooper()
        );

    } else {
        getLocationPermission();
    }

}

@SuppressLint({"MissingPermission"})
private final void updateLocationUI() {
    try {

        if (locationPermissionGranted) {

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        } else {


            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            lastKnownLocation = null;
            getLocationPermission();
        }
    } catch (SecurityException var2) {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", var2.getMessage(), var2);
    }

}

@SuppressLint({"MissingPermission"})
private final void getDeviceLocation() {
    try {
        if (locationPermissionGranted) {

            Task locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    MapsActivity.this.lastKnownLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                    if (MapsActivity.this.lastKnownLocation != null) {
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(new 
LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude())).title("Marker in 
Sydney").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(120.0F)));

                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new 
LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), 18.0F));
                    }
                } else {
                    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34.0D, 151.0D);

                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 18.0F));
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                }

            });
        }
    } catch (SecurityException var2) {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", var2.getMessage(), var2);
    }

}

private final void getLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), 
"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION") == 0) {
        locationPermissionGranted = true;
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
{"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }

}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] 
grantResults) {

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    locationPermissionGranted = false;
    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION && grantResults.length != 0 && 
grantResults[0] == 0) {
        locationPermissionGranted = true;
    }

    updateLocationUI();
}

}
```

DatabaseHandler class

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "VisitorDB";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

private static final String TABLE_LATLNG = "LATLNG";

private static final String KEY_TIME_STAMP = "time_stamp";
private static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
private static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    String CREATE_LATLNG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LATLNG + "("
            + KEY_TIME_STAMP + " INTEGER Primary key,"
            + KEY_LATITUDE + " DOUBLE,"
            + KEY_LONGITUDE + " DOUBLE" + ")";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_LATLNG_TABLE);

}

@SuppressLint("Range")
public MutableLiveData<TrackingEntity> getAllVisitors() {

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LATLNG + " ORDER BY " +
            KEY_TIME_STAMP + " DESC LIMIT 1";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    MutableLiveData<TrackingEntity> trackingEntityLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    TrackingEntity trackingEntity = new TrackingEntity();
    
 trackingEntity.setTimestamp(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
 (KEY_TIME_STAMP))));
    trackingEntity.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
  (KEY_LATITUDE))));
    trackingEntity.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
   (KEY_LONGITUDE))));

    trackingEntityLiveData.postValue(trackingEntity);

    // close db connection
    db.close();

    return trackingEntityLiveData;
}
```

}

Comment: Just a thought Since you are want to observe the changes in DB why not just use `android-room` its much easier to implement?

Comment: ya i have done this in room database but the requirement is for sql